# Table in responsive design

Tags: html, css

I would like to create a table which consists of 4 cells:

**Desktop**
The 4 cells should be next to each other: A B C D

**Mobile**

The 4 cells should form a 2 x 2 matrix, with the following sequence (like a snail):
A B

D C

Is there an elegant way to do this?

I dont know the solution

Comment: There is no dynamic way of "snaking" divs such as you suggest. It can be done **manually** but this is not sustainable and cannot really be scaled to many child elements in the absence of a pre-processor mixin.

Answer (score -3):

If you are not using any style library like tailwindcss or bootstrap then also its easy to do this by css,

assuming your html be like

```
<div class="grid-container">
    <div class="grid-item divA">A</div>
    <div class="grid-item divB">B</div>
    <div class="grid-item divC">C</div>
    <div class="grid-item divD">D</div>
</div>
```

you should apply css as

```
.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: 1fr;
    grid-column-gap: 0px;
    grid-row-gap: 0px;
}
.divA { grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 2; }
.divB { grid-area: 1 / 2 / 2 / 3; }
.divC { grid-area: 1 / 3 / 2 / 4; }
.divD { grid-area: 1 / 4 / 2 / 5; }

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .grid-container{
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
        grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
        grid-column-gap: 0px;
        grid-row-gap: 0px;
    }
    .divA { grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 2; }
    .divB { grid-area: 1 / 2 / 2 / 3; }
    .divD { grid-area: 2 / 1 / 3 / 2; }
    .divC { grid-area: 2 / 2 / 3 / 3; }
}
```

this will do the job.

Comment: You have C&D in the wrong order. https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/poYEmzp